# Selecting 10 names based on 10 highest numbers of other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select the top 10 voted restaurants, and plot them together.
So i want to create a plot that shows the restaurant names and their votes.
I used:

```
topTenVotes <- top_n(dataSet, 10, Votes)
```

and it showed me data of the columns in dataset based on the top 10 highest votes, however i want just the number of votes and restaurant names.

My Question is how to select only the top 10 highest votes and their restaurant names, and plotting them together?

expected output:

```
Restaurant Names            Votes
A                            300
B                            250 
C                            230  
D                            220
E                            210
F                            205
G                            200
H                            194
I                            160
J                            120
K                             34
```

And then a bar plot that shows these restaurant names and their votes

Comment: Try with `%>% select(yourcolumnnames)`  Not clear about the question.  Please show a small reproducible example/expected output

Comment: `top_n(restaurants, 10, Votes)` works. And so does `restaurants %>% top_n(10, Votes)`. What went wrong with your code?

Comment: I get this no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach with base functions creating another variable:

```
df <- data.frame(Names = LETTERS, Votes = sample(40:400, length(LETTERS)))
x <- df$Votes
names(x) <- df$Names # x <- setNames(df$Votes, df$Names) is another approach
barplot(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10], xlab = "Restaurant Name", ylab = "Votes")
```

Or a one-line solution with base functions:

```
barplot(sort(xtabs(Votes ~ Names, df), decreasing = TRUE)[1:10], xlab = "Restaurant Names")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a data set to use, so here's a minimal example to show how it might work:

```
library(tidyverse) 

df <- 
  tibble(
    restaurant = c("res1", "res2", "res3", "res4"),
    votes = c(2, 5, 8, 6)
  )

df %>% 
  arrange(-votes) %>% 
  head(3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(restaurant, votes), y = votes)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

The `top_n` command also works in this case but is designed for grouped data.

Answer (score 0):

Its more efficient, though less readable, to use base functions:

```
#toy data
d <- data.frame(list(Names = sample(LETTERS, size = 15), value = rnorm(25, 10, n = 15)))
head(d)
  Names     value
1     D 25.592749
2     B 28.362303
3     H  1.576343
4     L 28.718517
5     S 27.648078
6     Y 29.364797
#reorder by, and retain, the top 10
newdata <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {
      newdata <- rbind(newdata,d[which(d$value == sort(d$value, decreasing = T)[1:10][i]),])
}
newdata
   Names    value
8      W 45.11330
13     K 36.50623
14     P 31.33122
15     T 30.28397
6      Y 29.36480
7      Q 29.29337
4      L 28.71852
10     Z 28.62501
2      B 28.36230
5      S 27.64808
```